# Overriding Border style in a new window previously defined in Application Resources (possibly bug?)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've written a small test case for some behavior that I don't quite understand. If someone could clear this up for me, I'd be most interested.

I have, in App.xaml,

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Border">
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
          Value="Crimson" />
    </Style>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I would like to remove the style for the following window so I redefine the style as seen in the following: -

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

  <ListView>
    <ListView.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="Border" />
     </ListView.Resources>
     <ListView.View>
       <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn Header="test1" />
         <GridViewColumn Header="test2" />
       </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
</Window>
```

I was under the impression that if I were to redefine the style, as above, this would override what I put in the Application resources. I have tested with setting the border brush to no avail even though this shouldn't be required.

Below is a screen capture of the window for which I had assumed there be no border styling: -

[image: Test case window]

**Note** It seems to look fine in the designer but not at runtime. Furthermore this works for other target types EXCEPT border (Tested with TextBlock and a few other controls)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a setter for the BorderBrush in the style that you declared in your ListView resources?

Comment: Yes, I've investigated this; someone else wrote an answer similar but deleted it soon after. Unfortunately setting the border brush property does not seem to override that of the application resources. Furthermore, I was under the impression that redefining the style, as done in the window in my example, should block that of the global style. See http://blog.scrappydog.com/2009/02/applying-and-blocking-global-styles-in.html